# AppleScript: open current iTunes track in another program [Riffstation]

Tags: applescript

I'm new to AppleScript and not programmer, so I'm hoping someone can help me out...

I want to get the current track path in iTunes and open the file in another program [Riffstation]

seems like this should work, but it doesn't:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set songLocation to get location of current track
end tell

tell application "Riffstation"
    open songLocation
end tell
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Riffstation doesn't support AppleScript so you have to ask the Finder to open the file and pass it to Riffstation

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set songLocation to get location of current track
end tell
tell application "Finder" to open songLocation using application file id "com.SonicLadder.Riffstation"
```

If you want to ignore .m4p files use

```
tell application "iTunes" to set {location:songLocation, kind:songKind} to current track
if songKind is not "Protected AAC audio file" then
    tell application "Finder" to open songLocation using application file id "com.SonicLadder.Riffstation"
end if
```

Comment: vadian, your AppleScript worked flawlessly until yesterday. now, whenever Riffstation opens I get the spinning beach ball and Riffstation becomes non-reponsive.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any experience with Riffstation.

Comment: I figured out the problem! thanks for the response. Riffstation can't open .m4p files.

Comment: is there a way to tell this AppleScript to not open .m4p files?